# Audio file captured by MediaRecorder is broken after it is sent to server using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, audio, retrofit2, android-mediacodec, mediarecorder

My app records an audio clip and send the clip to the server using Retrofit2 after the recording is completed.The file is received in server,but the file is broken,what I mean by broken is that it cannot be played. I use the following URL(example url:`mydomain.co/audio/myaudio.mp4`) to play the audio clip,which I tried with another audio file using `postman`,the audio file can be played successfully.Besides,even downloading the audio clip captured by android via `Filezilla` also has the same broken file.

This is how I record the audio:

```
private void startRecordingAudio() {
    Log.d("audiorecording","recording sound");
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

    MediaFileHelper fileHelper = new MediaFileHelper();
    audioOutputFile = fileHelper.getOutputAudioFile();
    recorder.setOutputFile(audioOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the file path of the audio files:

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myapp/AUDIO_20171023143717.mp4

To solve this,I tried using different codec and different output format,as follows

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THERE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THERE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
```

I have also tried to change the file extension to `.mp3` , `.mp4` and `.3gpp` as well,but none of them seem to work on the server side.
To make things clear, I've attach the code which I used to send the audio file to server using `Retrofit2`:

```
private void sendAudioToServer( final String audioFilePath,final String api_key){
    Log.d("AUDIO FILE PATH",audioFilePath);
    File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);
    RequestBody audioBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/*"), audioFilePath);
    MultipartBody.Part aFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("audio", audioFile.getName(), audioBody);

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    okhttp3.Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                    ongoing.addHeader("authorization", api_key);
                    return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
                }
            })
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();

    AudioInterface audioInterface = retrofit.create(AudioInterface.class);
    Call<ResultObject> serverCom = audioInterface.sendAudioToServer(aFile);

    serverCom.enqueue(new Callback<ResultObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResultObject> call, retrofit2.Response<ResultObject> response) {
            ResultObject result = response.body();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result.getSuccess())){
                Log.d("audio Result " , result.getSuccess());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResultObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("audio error",t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

My question is:

1)what is the correct way to send the audio file to server from android?

2) if the problem is about the codec for the audio recorder,what is the correct codec for audio file? Cause later the same audio I need to support Ios and website as well..

Somebody please give some suggestion.Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

I try to play the recorded audio file using `MediaPlayer`,the file path is like this

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Myapp/AUDIO_20171026135950.mp4

Here is my code to play the audio file above

```
String audioFile = " /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Myapp/AUDIO_20171026135950.mp4";
audioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(audioFile);
                        try{
                            mp.setDataSource(mContext,uri);
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.start();
                        }catch (IOException E){
                            E.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But it throws me the following exception, when I play the local audio file:

> W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Myapp/AUDIO_20171026135950.mp4

If I play the URL from server,it throw this exception:

```
10-26 14:06:05.551 8806-8806/? W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1163)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-26 14:06:05.552 8806-8806/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did your audio file playable in your android phone?

Comment: @HarisQureshi hey bro,I just test to play the audio file using `MediaPlayer` but it throw me the exception  `W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myapp/AUDIO_20171026135950.mp4`

Comment: @HarisQureshi hey bro,I updated the question,kindly take a look

Comment: Try to remove bit and sample rate respectively and check.

Comment: I remove bit and sample rate,but when I try to play it,the exception still the same

Comment: Have you checked to verify that the file is actually there? Try changing "/storage/emulated/0/" to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "DCIM/myapp/AUDIO_20171026135950.mp4"

Comment: When playing the file locally, try

Uri.fromFile(new File(audioFile));  
instead of

Uri.parse(audioFile);

Comment: ok @Mars I will try it later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setAudioEncodingBitRate` is very low.

**it should be  16000 for 16hz and not just 16**

try it with 16000 or 32000 in `setAudioEncodingBitRate` value

comment here if it works or not, i'll try to help you out more

Comment: I change the value to 16000 and 32000 and test using emulator..but it still cant work,cant play in the URL I assign to it

Comment: Emulator mostly fails with MediaRecorder
Try it in real device !

Stated in Android Developer Guide

Note: Currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Comment: ok nice bro..this is nice..let me test again and let you..really thank you

Comment: @ken let me know if you have any quality issue also while recording. i would appreciate if you can rate the answer if it was helpful. cheers !

Comment: Hey bro,I tested by using real device.and setting the value as you mention,but in server,I still cant play the audio file..

Comment: therefore when I load back the URL assign to this audio file to Android side..the file cannot play

Comment: buzz me over skype so i can see details and give you solution soon !
Skype id : cattechsol.com